# Unable to write Silverstripe 4 error log to email

Tags: php, error-handling, silverstripe-4

I have put these codes to .yml file and I am still not getting emails with errors

```
SilverStripe\Core\Injector\Injector:
    Psr\Log\LoggerInterface:
      calls:
        MailHandler: [ pushHandler, [ '%$MailHandler' ] ]
    MailHandler:
      class: Monolog\Handler\NativeMailerHandler
      constructor:
        - abc@sss.com
        - There was an error on your test site
        - abc@sss.com
        - error
      properties:
        ContentType: text/html
        Formatter: %$SilverStripe\Logging\DetailedErrorFormatter
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned which version of Silverstripe 4 you're using, so I'll assume it's one of the latest minor releases.

Since 4.4.0 (I think) Silverstripe does not write to the default `LoggerInterface` handler for core error handling, allowing you to use it for custom app logging instead. If you're a version from 4.4 onwards, and you want to send application errors to your mail handler, you will need to use the `Psr\Log\LoggerInterface.errorhandler` instance instead:

```
SilverStripe\Core\Injector\Injector:
  Psr\Log\LoggerInterface.errorhandler:
    ...
```

You should also ensure that you've correctly [configured your email driver](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/email/).

Comment: I used silverstripe 4 version

Comment: You can find out which version you're using by running `composer show silverstripe/framework`

Comment: versions : * 4.1.2

Comment: i have already put the line below and still the errors are not coming to the email. Do i have to edit .env file or _config.php                                                                                                        Psr\Log\LoggerInterface.errorhandler:

Comment: Ok, you're using an old version of Silverstripe 4 so the configuration you had already is correct. Do other emails work in your system? Have you read the docs I linked to for configuring your email driver?